# Rust type hint with method call syntax

Tags: syntax, rust, traits, type-hinting, method-call

Is there a way to provide a type hint for a trait method without moving the receiver into the argument list?

For instance, if I have some x and call

```
x.foo(y)
```

and I need to clarify that foo is a method of the trait T, do I have to write it as:

```
<_ as T>::foo(x, y)
```

or is there some syntax that looks more like

```
x::<as T>.foo(y)
```

that I can use?

Comment: BTW `<_ as T>::foo` can be written `T::foo`

Comment: Oh, right. But that still looks less like a method call and more like a function call.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to make sure that the trait T is in scope with a `use` statement...